# How can I streamline my code to stop it crashing the server?

Tags: mysql

I want to find the max value in the Distance_KM column. Here's my code...

```
SELECT Source_Airport, Destination_Airport, Airline, Source_LAT, Source_LONG, Destination_LAT,  Destination_LONG,
(111.045*DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(Source_LAT)) * COS(RADIANS(Destination_LAT)) *
             COS(RADIANS(Source_LONG) - RADIANS(Destination_LONG)) +
             SIN(RADIANS(Source_LAT)) * SIN(RADIANS(Destination_LAT))))) as Distance_KM 
FROM  

(SELECT 
    routes.Source_Airport AS Source_Airport,
    routes.Destination_Airport AS Destination_Airport,
    routes.Airline AS Airline,
    S.Latitude AS Source_LAT,
    S.Longitude AS Source_LONG,
    D.Latitude AS Destination_LAT,
    D.Longitude AS Destination_LONG
FROM
    ROUTES
        INNER JOIN
    airports AS S ON S.Airport_ID = routes.Source_Airport_ID
        INNER JOIN
    airports AS D ON D.Airport_ID = routes.Destination_Airport_ID) as Airport_Dist
```

Which produces a table which looks like this...

```
                                                                  Distance_KM
YYZ YAM AC  43.67720032 -79.63059998    46.48500061 -84.50939941    493.34801024280597
YUL YBC AC  45.47060013 -73.74079895    49.13249969 -68.20439911    582.0897139062885
YYY YBC AC  48.60860062 -68.20809937    49.13249969 -68.20439911    58.1770000072475
YUL YBG AC  45.47060013 -73.74079895    48.33060074 -70.99639893    379.706058161593
YCS YBK 5T  63.34690094 -90.73110199    64.29889679 -96.07779694    282.3404661252172
YRT YBK 5T  62.81140137 -92.11579895    64.29889679 -96.07779694    256.1877034117866
YRT YBK 7F  62.81140137 -92.11579895    64.29889679 -96.07779694    256.1877034117866
YUT YBK 7F  66.52140045 -86.22470093    64.29889679 -96.07779694    517.0880293513636
YQQ YBL 8P  49.71080017 -124.887001 49.95080185 -125.2710037    38.299320607992
```

To find the greatest value in the Distance_KM column I thought i'd just simply wrap the formula (which produces the column) with a MAX() function like so...

***MAX(***(111.045*DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(Source_LAT)) * COS(RADIANS(Destination_LAT)) *
             COS(RADIANS(Source_LONG) - RADIANS(Destination_LONG)) +
             SIN(RADIANS(Source_LAT)) * SIN(RADIANS(Destination_LAT)))))***)*** as Distance_KM

I expected the script to return the entry with the greatest distance but instead it crashes the server.

Why is this not working??

Comment: If your query runs in a reasonable length of time, why not sort Distance_KM DESC and LIMIT 1?  You would be DONE.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it didn't really **crash** the server - it "just" kept him busy for hours, days or months.

This method of calculating a distance doesn't scale very good: It is extremly computation-intensive.

You have a few options:

- trade CPU against storage and create a distance table, that is maintained via `ON AFTER UPDATE`, `ON AFTER INSERT` and `ON AFTER DELETE` triggers on your airport table. This way you have the distances easily avaliable, and a few thousand airports will only give you a some million possible distances. Since the airport table isn't updated often, the triggers will most likely be no problems.
- Use an optimized algorithm: First calculate the orthogonal distance (simply the differences) relying on the box theorem to create a highly reduced candidate table, then run your `MAX` over this.

Comment: I've already worked out what the distances between the airports are from the Source and Destination airport LAT and LONG using the Haversine Formula and the results are in the Distance_KM column. I simply want to find the greatest value in that column without breaking my computer haha

Comment: You have **not** worked out those values - you have instead worked out **how to calculate them in an extremly costly way.** If you run this query over a few thousand airports and apply aggregation you will keep your server very busy for a very long time. You need to break down this big chunk of calculation into more manageable pieces.

Comment: So could I do this by creating a new table and then inserting the results into said table, then running the max function on the new table?

Comment: If you have the storage to do so, this looks like a reasonable way.